# How do I fix this error `warning: Dependency 'Qt.webengine' not found for product '. `?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qmake, qbs

I am getting this error when saving QBS:
[image: I am getting this error when saving QBS]

```
warning: Dependency 'Qt.webengine' not found for product 'anime-dl'.
```

Here is the profile in the settings::
[image: Here is the profile in the settings:]

This should not be happening because I built this explicitly, as well as it does not happen if I throw this in a QMake Project File:

```
QT += core gui multimedia webengine webenginewidgets multimediawidgets
```

And its included in the qt that I built:

```
➜  Qt-5.15.2 ll include
total 472K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DAnimation
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DCore
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DExtras
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DInput
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DLogic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DQuick
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DQuickAnimation
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DQuickExtras
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DQuickInput
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DQuickRender
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DQuickScene2D
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  12K Jan 22 20:16 Qt3DRender
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtAccessibilitySupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtBluetooth
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtBodymovin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtCharts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtConcurrent
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  20K Jan 22 20:15 QtCore
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtDataVisualization
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtDBus
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtDesigner
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtDesignerComponents
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtDeviceDiscoverySupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtEdidSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtEglFSDeviceIntegration
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtEglSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtEventDispatcherSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtFbSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtFontDatabaseSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtGamepad
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtGlxSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  20K Jan 22 20:15 QtGui
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtHelp
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtInputSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtKmsSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtLinuxAccessibilitySupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtLocation
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  12K Jan 22 20:16 QtMultimedia
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtMultimediaGstTools
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtMultimediaQuick
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtMultimediaWidgets
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtNetwork
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtNetworkAuth
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtNfc
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtOpenGL
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtOpenGLExtensions
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtPacketProtocol
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtPdf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtPdfWidgets
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtPlatformCompositorSupport
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtPlatformHeaders
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtPositioning
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtPositioningQuick
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtPrintSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtPurchasing
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQml
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQmlDebug
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQmlModels
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQmlWorkerScript
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQuick
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuick3D
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuick3DAssetImport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuick3DRender
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuick3DRuntimeRender
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuick3DUtils
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuickControls2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQuickParticles
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQuickShapes
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtQuickTemplates2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQuickTest
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtQuickWidgets
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtRemoteObjects
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtRepParser
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtScript
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtScriptTools
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtScxml
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtSensors
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtSerialBus
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtSerialPort
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtServiceSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtSql
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtSvg
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtTest
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtTextToSpeech
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtThemeSupport
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtUiPlugin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtUiTools
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtVirtualKeyboard
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtVulkanSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtWaylandClient
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtWaylandCompositor
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtWebChannel
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtWebEngine
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtWebEngineCore
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtWebEngineWidgets
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtWebSockets
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:17 QtWebView
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  20K Jan 22 20:15 QtWidgets
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtX11Extras
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtXkbCommonSupport
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:15 QtXml
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 20:16 QtXmlPatterns
```

How can I fix this error? I am fairly certain it must be detecting the system installed version of Qt, as opposed to the one I built, and yet in profiles, it should be pointing to the one I built.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me with `charts` module, then I realised C++ and qml modules are separated, so same thing might be the case for `webengine` too. Trying `sudo apt-get install -y qml-module-qtwebengine` might help.

Comment: @Kao Was already installed for what its worth.

Comment: If QtWebengine was installed after the project was originally opened, then that would be expected, and checking "Force Probes" in the project's build settings will solve the problem. (Check the box, wait for the project to get re-resolved, then uncheck it again.) Otherwise, I don't see how this could happen, assuming the Qt installation is not messed up, ie <qt base dir>/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webengine.pri exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what was going on, but I did manage to settle the issue by switching from `Desktop Kit` to the `Imported Kit`, despite both of them having as far as I can tell, the same settings.